# dictionary insert causes error 'an item with the same key has already been added'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

`enter code here`I keep running into this exception with ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

The project has two simple classess. Project and Orders. Creation of Project works fine but when I try to create an order it keeps failing with the excption below.

> {"requestigAppLead":"ddd","requestingApplication":"sad","responsibleApp":"fff","responsibleAppLead":"ddd"}[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.] 
>          System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52 
>          System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +9374523 
>          System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) +252

I still see the same issue. Below are complete details.

```
@model DART.Models.Order

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Submit your order.</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#orderStatusID").change(function () {
            if ($("#orderStatusID").val() == "8") { // blocked by defect
                $("#divDefectDetails").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#divDefectDetails").hide();
            }
        });


        $("#projectID").change(function () {
            //alert("select changed!!!" + $("#projectID").val());
            var ur = "/SelectProject/" + $("#projectID").val();
            var query = $("#projectID").val();


            if (query == "") {
                $("#requesterLead").val("");
                $("#requestingApp").val("");
                $("#responsibleApp").val("");
                $("#responsibleLead").val("");
                return;
            }

            // get the JASON object back from Controler.
            // use the data to load the values into form
            $.getJSON("/Order/SelectProject", { id: query }, function (data) {
                //alert("data===" + data);
                jQuery.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    if (key == "requestigAppLead") {
                        $("#requesterLead").val(val);
                    }
                    else if (key == "requestingApplication") {
                        $("#requestingApp").val(val);
                    }
                    else if (key == "responsibleApp") {
                        $("#responsibleApp").val(val);
                    }
                    else if (key == "responsibleAppLead") {
                        $("#responsibleLead").val(val);
                    }

                });
            });
        });
    })
</script>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter Your Order Detalis</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.projectProjectID, "Project")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field" id="divProjectId">
            @Html.DropDownList("projectID","Select Project")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.projectProjectID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Requester Lead")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.requesterLead)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.requesterLead)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Responsible CUID")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.responsibleCUID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.responsibleCUID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Responsible Lead")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.responsibleLead)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.responsibleLead)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Requesting Application")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.requestingApp)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.requestingApp)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Responsible Application")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.responsibleApplication)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.responsibleApplication)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("RCBSCode")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.rcbsCode)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.rcbsCode)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Order Request Details")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.orderRequestDetails,"width=100%")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.orderRequestDetails)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Order Request Complete Details")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.orderRequestCompleteDetails)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.orderRequestCompleteDetails)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("CreatedBy")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.createdby)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.createdby)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("UpdatedBy")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.updatedBy)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.updatedBy)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.status, "OrderStatus")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field" id="divStatus">
            @Html.DropDownList("orderStatusID", "Select Order Status")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)
        </div>

        <div id="divDefectDetails" style="display:none">

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Defect ID")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.defectID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.defectID)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("QC Project Name")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.qcProjectName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.qcProjectName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("QC Application")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.application)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.application)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("QC Status")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.status)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.status)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("QC EFD")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.efd)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.efd)
            </div>

        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="CreateOrder" name="CreateOrder" value="Create Order" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

Control Code:

//
// GET: /Order/Create
public ActionResult Create( )
{
    ViewBag.projectID = new SelectList(db.Projects.ToList(), "projectID", "projectName");
    ViewBag.orderStatusID = new SelectList(db.OrderStatuses.ToList(), "orderStatusID", "description");
    return View();
}
```

Adding  more details as requested below.

```
    //
    // Populate project details
    //
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual JsonResult SelectProject(long? id)
    {
        Project project = this.db.Projects.Find(1);
        var result = new { project.requestigAppLead,
                           project.requestingApplication,
                            project.responsibleApp,
                           project.responsibleAppLead
                          };


        //ViewBag.projectID = new SelectList(db.Projects, "projectID", "projectName",id.ToString());

        //return View(order);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

            //
    // POST: /Order/Create
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create(Order order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //
            // TO DO: if the order count is more than threshold raise an alert to the user and send an email to 
            // leads
            //

            order.createDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            order.updateDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // send email
            util.EmailUtil.SendEmail(order);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.projectID = new SelectList(db.Projects, "projectID", "projectName", order.projectProjectID);
        return View(order);
    }
```

Comment: The exception is not as important as the **code actually causing the exception**. Edit your question to include the code where you're inserting into the dictionary.

Comment: Is the JSON shown the entire body of the request which fails?  If not, please show all of the JSON being submitted.

Comment: I have added the code above to show the HttpGet and HttpPost methods. Included is also a method that is used toget Jason data when user selects the Project Dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Your linq query contains a duplicate entry. You need to figure out what that is and remove it OR if possible use .ToList() and not ToDictionary()